# How to make stopwatch pause in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am working on stopwatch. If I select the start button the timer is running fine. But when I press the button again with the following code. Then the timer starts from beginning 00:00:00. I want to pause the timer and if I press it, again it should start from the paused time, not from the beginning time. How to do this task? Any other ideas are also accepted.

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      TimeSpan runTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(System.Environment.TickCount - _startTime);
      timeLabel.Text = runTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }

     private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
              if (_timer.IsEnabled)
              {
                _watcher.Stop();
                _timer.Stop();
                StartButton.Content = "Start";
              }
              else
              {
                _watcher.Start();
                _timer.Start();
                _startTime = System.Environment.TickCount;
                StartButton.Content = "Stop";
              }
            }
```

Comment: are u setting _startTime variable only once in StartButton_Click? If you want to calculate the timespan between two button clicks you just need one stopwatch(here you have used two i think timer and watcher). One click will start it and other click will stop it and will check the Elapsed property to get the timespan. Stopwatch.Start() start or resumes the stopwatch not reset it

Comment: @nit : watcher belongs to GeoCoordinateWatcher. When I press it, app stops tracking the location. watcher is different from timer.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the timer time when you click on stop button and change your code when you click on start button.

Start button :
Check if _refreshTimeTimer is not null
well

```
if(_refreshTimeTimer != null){
      Timer t = new timer(_refreshTimeTimer );
      // Start new timer
      _refreshTimeTimer = null;
}else{
      if (_timer.IsEnabled)
          {
            _watcher.Stop();
            _timer.Stop();
            StartButton.Content = "Start";
          }
          else
          {
            _watcher.Start();
            _timer.Start();
            _startTime = System.Environment.TickCount;
            StartButton.Content = "Stop";
          }
}
```

Stop button :

```
_refreshTimeTimer = _timer.getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare dispatcher time , run timer at what time do you want to pause then start your first time add dispatcher timer value it will start from before paused time.